# Acts_as_commentable_with_threading javascript toggle not working with rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I've been trying to get [this tutorial](http://dustinfisher.com/acts-as-commentable-with-threading-gem/) to work with my rails 5 project, but apparently there has been some change in javascript since rails 4, which causes the reply field to immediately close upon clicking "reply". It's supposed to stay open until you've typed in a message and clicked the "Post comment" button next to it.

There is a comment from 6 days ago suggesting js code that works with rails 5, but it does not work for me. (do I have to change something with the anchor and span he mentions?)

I have followed the guide exactly, even made an entirely new project, and still no luck.
What change needs to be made to the javascript code to make it compatible with rails 5?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact problem and I found a solution that worked well for me. I'm not sure of any hidden implications, but so far I haven't found any concerns. All I did was take the html link in the "comment-nav" div class and convert it from a "#" into a ".". I then modified the javascript to "return false;". I followed the same tutorial. I am using Rails 5. I know this answer is very late, but wanted to answer for any future people with this problem.

Here is my html:

```html
<% comments.each do |comment| %>  
  <div class="comments-show">
    <div class="comment">
      <p><%= comment.body %><br></p>
      <div class="comment-nav"><a href="." class="comment-reply">Reply</a></div>
      <div class="reply-form">
        <%= form_for @new_comment do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id, value: @new_comment.commentable_id %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type, value: @new_comment.commentable_type %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :comment_id, value: comment.id %>
          <div class="field form-group">
            <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control' %>
          </div>
          <div class="field form-group">
            <%= submit_tag "Post Reply", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: "comments/reply", locals: {comments: comment.children} %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And here is my javascript:

```js
$ ->
  $('.comment-reply').click ->
    $(this).closest('.comment').find('.reply-form').toggle()
    return false;
```